# SQL Query Solution - Day By Day Balance

Tags: sql, mysql

First of all, let me explain the table structure. It is as follows.

- Main Table - **CategoryGroup**
- Fields - CatGroupID, GroupName, GroupType
- Sample Data

  CatGroupID |      GroupName |     GroupType 
  1          |  Utility       | Expense
  2          |  Auto          | Expense
  3          |  Misc.         | Expense
  4          |  Income        | Income
  5          |  HouseHold     | Expense
- Child Table - **TransactionCategory**
- Fields - CategoryID, CatGroupID, CatName,CatImgName
- Sample Data

  CategoryID |      CatGroupID |     CatName   | CatImgName 
  1          |  1       | Water | Water.png
  2          |  1          | Phone | Phone.png
  3          |  1         | Electricity | Ele.png
  4          |  2        | Auto | Auto.png
  5          |  2     | Gas | Gas.png
- Child Child Table - **TransactionTbl**
- Fields - rowid, UserID, ProfileID, CategoryID,TraID, TraDate,TraAmt
- Sample Data

  rowid(AutoInc) | UserID | ProfileID | CategoryID | TraID | TraDate | TraAmt 
  1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2010-1-1 | 1000.00
  2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2010-1-2 | 250.00

I have tried to many queries - and one of them is as follows,

> select A.TraDate,A.TraAmt,C.GroupType,B.CatName from transactionTbl A, TransactionCategory B,CategoryGroup C
>   where A.TraDate='2010-01-11' and A.CAtegoryID=B.CategoryID and B.CatGroupID=C.CatGroupID

I am an iPhone developer & using SQLite. I have very little ideas regarding database management & queries & joins. just because of this I have to ask here.

My required output is as follows.

TraID | TraDate | CatName | Amount | Balance | 
1. | 2010-1-1 | Income | 5000.00 | 5000.00 | 
2. | 2010-1-2 | Auto | 250.00 | 4750.00 | 
3. | 2010-1-3 | Gas | 200.00 | 4550.00 |
4. | 2010-1-4 | Income | 500 | 5050.00 |

Please observe each row above.

- If I have income transaction, it should add to balance, and
- If I have expense transaction, it should subtract from balance.

**Edit :**

I have found some solution - a little. But it's yet not as I want.

```
select A.traID,B.CatName,C.GroupType,A.TraDate,A.TraAmt from transactionTbl A,TransactionCategory B,CategoryGroup C 
where A.CategoryID=B.CategoryID and B.CatGroupID=C.CatGroupID
order by A.TraDate,A.TraID
```

It gives output as follows.

TraID   CatName GroupType   TraDate TraAmt  
-----   ------- ---------   ------- ------  
1   Income  Income  2010-01-01  5000    
2   Income  Income  2010-01-02  4500    
3   Water   Expense 2010-01-03  450 
4   Phone   Expense 2010-01-03  450 
5   Electricity Expense 2010-01-03  650
 
6   Auto    Expense 2010-01-03  750 
7   Auto    Expense 2010-01-03  450 
8   Gas Expense 2010-01-05  750 
9   Misc    Expense 2010-01-06  800 
10  Health  Expense 2010-01-13  250 
11  Tax Expense 2010-01-21  450 
12  Investments Expense 2010-01-22  450
 
13  Credit Cards    Expense 2010-01-27  550 
14  Eat Out Expense 2010-01-29  450

The last thing is remaining to implement  that is balance managing.
like here - balance should be as follows

Balance 
1. 5000
2. 9500
3. 9050 and so on.

Comment: Do you want output for every day from the first one you specified, or only for days on which transactions occured?

Comment: Balance after each transaction. Not day by day. Sir @ lins313159 - I have edited my question. Check it out. Please inform me, if more info is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this gives the right results, I'm not sure if it is the optimal way to do it in MySQL in terms of performance.

```
SELECT
  A.traID,
  B.CatName,
  C.GroupType,
  A.TraDate,
  A.TraAmt,
  SUM(D.TraAmt) as Balance
FROM transactionTbl A
INNER JOIN TransactionCategory B
    ON A.CategoryID=B.CategoryID
INNER JOIN CategoryGroup C
    ON B.CatGroupID=C.CatGroupID
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
          A.TraDate,
          CASE WHEN C.GroupType = 'Income' THEN A.TraAmt ELSE -A.TraAmt END AS TraAmt
        FROM transactionTbl A
        INNER JOIN TransactionCategory B
            ON A.CategoryID=B.CategoryID
        INNER JOIN CategoryGroup C
            ON B.CatGroupID=C.CatGroupID) D
    ON A.TraDate >= D.TraDate
GROUP BY
  A.traID,
  B.CatName,
  C.GroupType,
  A.TraDate,
  A.TraAmt
ORDER BY
  A.TraDate,
  A.TraID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the solution in my way. ( Actually my project manager told me the query to implement - when I asked to him. )

```
select A1.traID,B1.CatName,C1.GroupType,A1.TraDate,A1.TraAmt,            
    (select total(A.TraAmt)              
      from transactionTbl A,TransactionCategory B,CategoryGroup C 
      where A.CategoryID=B.CategoryID and B.CatGroupID=C.CatGroupID
      AND A.traID <= A1.traID AND C.GroupType = 'Income' and A.userID=1 and A.profileID=1
      order by A.TraDate,A.TraID) 
      -
      (select total(A.TraAmt) 
      from transactionTbl A,TransactionCategory B,CategoryGroup C 
      where A.CategoryID=B.CategoryID and B.CatGroupID=C.CatGroupID
      AND A.traID <= A1.traID AND C.GroupType = 'Expense' and A.userID=1 and A.profileID=1
      order by A.TraDate,A.TraID) 
     as BalanceAmt
  from transactionTbl A1,TransactionCategory B1,CategoryGroup C1 
where A1.CategoryID=B1.CategoryID and B1.CatGroupID=C1.CatGroupID 
and A1.userID=1 and A1.profileID=1
order by A1.TraDate,A1.TraID
```